# Why am I getting an unsupported block type error in Terraform while setting up an Azure Kubernetes cluster?

Tags: azure, kubernetes, terraform, azure-aks, terraform-provider-azure

Not sure why terraform will not accept the following code below. I keep getting the block is not  expected here error. Please see below main.tf and vairable.tf

Azure Kubernetes cluster => unsupported block type error

ERROR MESSAGE

az terraform error blocks of type "role_based_access_control" are not expected here.
az terraform error blocks of type "addon_profile" are not expected here.

```
### MAIN.TF
# Configure the Azure Provider
terraform {
  required_providers {
    azurerm = {
      source = "hashicorp/azurerm"
      version = ">= 2.26"
    }
  }

  backend "azurerm" {
    resource_group_name   = "rg-eastus-services-terraform"
    storage_account_name  = "cchmceuststate9824"
    container_name        = "tfstate"
    key                   = "aks-roadmab.dev.terraform03.tfstate"
  }
}

# Providers

provider "azurerm" {
  features {}
}

# Resource group reference
data "azurerm_resource_group" "example" {
  name     = var.resourcegroup
}

# Resources

resource "azurerm_log_analytics_workspace" "aks" {
  name                = "${var.prefix}-logA-ws"
  location            = data.azurerm_resource_group.example.location
  resource_group_name = data.azurerm_resource_group.example.name
  sku                 = "PerGB2018"
  retention_in_days   = 30
}

resource "azurerm_kubernetes_cluster" "example" {
  name                = var.aksname
  location            = data.azurerm_resource_group.example.location
  resource_group_name = data.azurerm_resource_group.example.name
  dns_prefix          = var.prefix
  kubernetes_version  = var.kubernetes_version
  azure_policy_enabled = true

  default_node_pool {
    name       = "default"
    node_count = 2
    vm_size    = "Standard_D2s_v3"
    enable_auto_scaling = true
    min_count           = "2"
    max_count           = "3"
    os_disk_size_gb     = 30
    type                = "VirtualMachineScaleSets"
    only_critical_addons_enabled = true
  }

  identity {
    type = "SystemAssigned"
  }

 role_based_access_control {
    enabled = true

    azure_active_directory {
      managed = true
      admin_group_object_ids = ["xxxxxxcd-75d2-4186-bac8-0fad5c2e110c"]
    }    
  }

addon_profile {
    oms_agent {
      enabled                    = true
      log_analytics_workspace_id = azurerm_log_analytics_workspace.aks.id
    }
    kube_dashboard {
      enabled = false
    }
    azure_policy {
      enabled = true
    }
  }

  tags = {
    Environment = "Demo"
  }
}

resource "azurerm_kubernetes_cluster_node_pool" "example" {
  name                  = "usernp1"
  kubernetes_cluster_id = azurerm_kubernetes_cluster.example.id
  vm_size               = "Standard_D4s_v3"
  node_count            = 2
  enable_auto_scaling = false
 # min_count           = "1"
 # max_count           = "1"

  tags = {
    Environment = "UserAppPool"
  }
}

output "client_certificate" {
  value = azurerm_kubernetes_cluster.example.kube_config.0.client_certificate
}

output "kube_config" {
  value = azurerm_kubernetes_cluster.example.kube_config_raw
}

### VAIABLES.TF

variable "resourcegroup" {
  description = "The Azure AD group that will be a cluster admin"
  default = "rg-eastus-services-roadmab"
}

variable "prefix" {
  description = "A dns prefix used for the k8s api"
  default = "sb-roadmabaks03-dns"
}

variable "aksname" {
  description = "The AKS Name of the cluster"
  default = "sb-roadmab3AKS"
}

variable "kubernetes_version" {
  description = "The kubernetes version to deploy"
  default = "1.26.3"
}

variable "aad_group_name" {
  description = "The Azure AD group that will be a cluster admin"
  default = "az-aksadmins"
}
```

Answer (score 1):

This is because there is no block argument with that name in the `azurerm_kubernetes_cluster` resource for the latest version of the `azurerm` provider (v3.58.0). There is an argument with name `role_based_access_control_enabled` which is by default set to `true`. It seems you actually want `azure_active_directory_role_based_access_control` block. The `addon_profile` block does not exist, but there are some arguments which seem to do what you want. To summarize, here is how the offending part should look like:

```
resource "azurerm_kubernetes_cluster" "example" {
 ... rest of the code ...
 azure_policy_enabled = true # this is already configured, there is no argument azure_policy

 azure_active_directory_role_based_access_control {
      managed                = true
      admin_group_object_ids = ["xxxxxxcd-75d2-4186-bac8-0fad5c2e110c"]
 }

 oms_agent {
   log_analytics_workspace_id = azurerm_log_analytics_workspace.aks.id
 }

  tags = {
    Environment = "Demo"
  }
}
```

However, I did not manage to find any reference for the `kube_dashboard` argument.